# How to detect overflow in one's complement system?

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture, digital-logic

In one's complement system in order to show negative binary number we simply complement each bit. Fore example :
+3= 0011  , -3= 1100

In two's complement systems we detect overflow using carry bit, but how about one's complement?

Comment: From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations: "This numeric representation system was common in older computers; the PDP-1, CDC 160 series, and UNIVAC 1100/2200 series, among many others, used ones'-complement arithmetic."

Answer (score 3):

The rules for detecting overflow in a two's complement sum are simple, and I also derive that for 1'complement:

1. If the sum of two positive numbers yields a negative result, the sum has overflowed.
2. If the sum of two negative numbers yields a positive result, the sum has overflowed.
3. Otherwise, the sum has not overflowed.

Addition is same as 2's complement except that instead of discarding the last carry, it is added to the n-bit sum in the right-most position ("end-around" carry). Take a look at following examples:

```
Pos + Neg numbers, Neg > Pos
+5  0101
-6  1001
-1  1110 (correct answer)
```

Different sign, and no overflow occurs.

```
Pos + Neg numbers, Pos > Neg
-5  1010
+6  0110
(1) 0000
1 (end-around carry)
+1  0001 (correct; no overflow)
```

End-around carry happens, but there isn't any overflow

```
-3  1100
-4  1011
(1) 0111
 1 (end-around carry)
-7  1000 (correct; no overflow)
```

Negative numbers which are |sum| <= 2^(n-1)

```
-5  1010
-6  1001
(1) 0011
 1 (end-around carry)
 0100 (wrong answer; overflow)
```

Negative number which are |sum| > 2^(n-1). Additionally, both has same similar sign and result has different sign.

Comment: If you're claiming that this also applies to one's complement, you should say so.  You only ever mention two's complement.  Rules 1-3 do look correct for one's complement, though.

Answer (score 0):

For one's complement, you can use the same overflow condition as is used for two's complement.

Let me illustrate with 3-bit numbers.

One's complement:

```
011   -4 overflows into +3
100   -3 lowest possible number
101   -2
110   -1
111   -0
000   +0
001   +1
010   +2
011   +3 highest possible number
100   +4 overflows into -3
```

Two's complement:

```
011   -5 overflows into +3
100   -4 lowest possible number
101   -3
110   -2
111   -1
000    0
001   +1
010   +2
011   +3 highest possible number
100   +4 overflows into -4
```

In both systems, the overflow can be detected by looking at the most significant bit. An overflow occurs:

- when the most significant bit goes from 0 to 1 while increasing the number
- when the most significant bit goes from 1 to 0 while decreasing the number

Comment: I think you didn't answer the question properly, just redefining problem.